# Sum of result from an assosiative array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [price] => 1.00
        [session_price] => 1.00
        [no_of_participants] => 1
        [session_id] => 1
        [coupon_id] => 0
        [group_discount_id] => 0
        [order_id] => 1
        [created] => 2015-04-02 16:56:24
        [modified] => 2015-04-02 16:56:24
    )
  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [price] => 2.00
        [session_price] => 2.00
        [no_of_participants] => 2
        [session_id] => 1
        [coupon_id] => 1
        [group_discount_id] => 1
        [order_id] => 1
        [created] => 2015-03-03 00:00:00
        [modified] => 2015-03-03 00:00:00
    )
   )
```

From the above I want total sum of `no_of_participants`(i.e `1 + 2 = 3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the array with a `foreach` and put the `no_of_participants` in a variable `$sum`

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $object){
  $sum = $sum + $object->no_of_participants;
}

echo $sum; //Returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($datas as $data){
    $sum += $data->no_of_participants;
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $object as defined in your question:

Then follow these steps:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $val){
    $sum = $sum + $val->no_of_participants;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = array_reduce(
    $myArrayOfObjects,
    function($runningTotal, $record) {
        $runningTotal += $record->no_of_participants;
        return $runningTotal;
    }
);
```